# Finding partitioning solution in R with pre-written Simulated annealing package?

Tags: r, optimization, simulated-annealing

I have a data set, which consists of a number of elements -- divided into two distinct categories (with an equal number of elements for each category) -- and with two continuous variables describing them, like so:

```
ID  |  Category  |  Variable_1  |  Variable_2
--------------------------------------------
1   |  Triangle  |  4.3522      |  5.2321
2   |  Triangle  |  3.6423      |  6.3223
3   |  Circle    |  5.2331      |  3.2452
4   |  Circle    |  2.6334      |  7.3443
... |  ...       |  ...         |  ...
```

Now, what I want to do is to create a list of one-to-one parings so that every element of category `Triangle` is paired to an element of category `Circle`, and so that the combined distance between the points within each pairing in a 2D space defined by `Variable_1` and `Variable_2` is as small as possible. In other words, if I had to travel from each `Triangle` element to a `Circle` element (but never to the same `Circle` element twice), I want to find out how to minimize the total traveling distance (see illustration below).

[image: Look at these pretty triangles and circles!]

Since I'm not really in the mood of trying to brute force this problem, I've been thinking that [Simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) probably would be a suitable optimisation method to use. I'd also like to work in R.

The good news is that I've found a couple of packages for doing Simulated annealing within R, for example [GenSA](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GenSA/index.html) and [optim](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/optim.html). The bad news is that I don't really know how to utilize these packages for my specific input needs. That is, as input I would like to specify a list of numbers denoting elements of a certain category in my list and in what order they should be paired to the other set of elements belonging to the other category. However, this would mean that I, in my Simulated annealing algoritm, only would like to use integers and that I never would like the same integer to appear twice, something that seems to go against how the packages above are implemented.

Is there some way that I could make effective use of some pre-written Simulated annealing package for R, or do I need to write my own methods for this problem?

Comment: Look here and give the guy an upvote: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13963652/1201032

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the best matching pairwise points from 2 vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961493/finding-the-best-matching-pairwise-points-from-2-vectors)