# 3-d point matching/clustering in R

Tags: r, pattern-matching, nearest-neighbor

I would like to match points in 3-dimensional space.

Therefore, I am using the Hungarian Method described in this question: [Finding the best matching pairwise points from 2 vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961493/finding-the-best-matching-pairwise-points-from-2-vectors)

Here is my example using R:

```
# packages
library(rgl)
library(clue)
library(plyr)
library(fields)

set.seed(1)
a <- c(rep(2,7), 3,4,5,6,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,7,7) # x values
b <- c(rep(3,7),3,3,3,3, 3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3) # y values
c <- c(seq(1,7),1,1,1,1,7,7,7,7,1,2,3,4,5,6) # z values

# transform the points
set.seed(2)
a1 <- a + seq(1,length(a)) 
b1 <- b + 8 
c1 <- c + 9 


# plot the data
plot3d(a,b,c,  col="red", pch=16,size=10)
plot3d(a1,b1,c1, lwd=10, col="blue", pch=16,size=10, add=TRUE)

# run the Hungarian Method
A <- cbind(a,b,c)
B <- cbind(a1,b1,c1)

distances <- rdist(A,B) # calculate Euclidean Distance between points
min.dist <- solve_LSAP(distances) # minimizing the sum of distance 

min.dist.num <- as.numeric(min.dist)

# plot the minimized lines between point sets
for (ii in 1:dim(B)[1]){

  D <- c(A[ii,1], B[min.dist.num[ii],1])
  R <- c(A[ii,2], B[min.dist.num[ii],2])
  W <- c(A[ii,3], B[min.dist.num[ii],3])
  segments3d(D,R,W,col=2,lwd=1)

}
# calculate the share of points that is matched correctly
sum(1:dim(B)[1]==min.dist.num)/dim(B)[1]* 100
```

[image: red: original ponts, blue: transformed points]

The problem here is that **only 5% of the points** are matched correctly (see last line of the code). In my view, the main trouble is that the algorithm does not take the **structure of the object (a square)** into account.

**Question: Is there any method that performs better for this sample data?**

In my original data, the dimensional structure of the points is way more complicated. I have a cloud of data and within this cloud there are multiple subfigures.

I am seeking primarily for a solution in R, but other implementations (e.g. MATLAB, Excel, Java) are also welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure SO is the best site for this question. That said, you might take a look at the `optmatch` package and related papers by Paul Rosenbaum and coauthors. This method attempts to minimize a "total network" distance function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What might be a better site? Cross Validated?

Comment: That's a good question. CV is probably a be a better fit, but it seems to that the question is something like computational mathematics. Finding an algorithm that satisfies some objective function.

Comment: Try preprocessing your data better. I.e. center your data, and standardize it.